# The irrational numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Is the set of irrational numbers minus a single point still dense?

Tags: real-analysis

The irrational numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Is the set of irrational numbers minus a single point still dense? Is the set still uncountable?

I am looking for a counter-example to a statement. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I think you meant to write\mathbbR so you get $\mathbb R$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing a single point changes neither *cardinality* nor *density* (at least, in this context).

---

First of all, if we remove a point from an uncountable set, it remains uncountable. This is easier to see in the other direction: if I have a countable set and I add a point to it, it stays countable (think about [Hilbert's hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel)).

- More generally, [the axiom of choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) implies that removing a single point never changes the cardinality of an infinite set: if $X$ is infinite and $x\in X$, then $X\setminus\{x\}$ has the same cardinality as $X$. *(We don't need the whole axiom of choice here, just a weak fragment of it - enough to rule out [sets which are infinite but Dedekind-finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set).)*

---

At least in the context of $\mathbb{R}$ - the situation can be different in other [topological spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space) - the same is true of density: if $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is dense, then so is $A\setminus\{x\}$ for any $x$. This is proved as follows:

- Suppose $A\setminus\{x\}$ is not dense. Then we can find some open interval $(a,b)$ with $(A\setminus\{x\})\cap (a,b)=\emptyset$.
- Since $A$ itself *is* dense, we must have $x\in (a,b)$.
- OK, but then $(a,x)\cap A=\emptyset$ - and this contradicts the density of $A$.